# Compiling CMPI code for python 3.0

Tags: c, python-3.x

I want to compile the cmpi-pywbem-bindings code for 3.0.

The problems are

1. I can't find the sourcecode (strange). Please let me know the links
2. Since it is a C code ( I know that part ), I need to change some specifics ( as the Python 3.x has changed internally a lot when compared to  2.x)

Comment: I can't find anything called cmpi-pybem. Are you sure that what you are looking for exists?

Comment: Yes, cmpi-pywbem-bindings , there are lots of rpms available but for python 2.x version

Comment: Ah, you misspelled it the first time around. It seems the project home is here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pywbem/index.php?title=Main_Page But it seems highly unmaintained. Ask on the mailing list.

Comment: Sign is removed, Please refer the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: Sure, I will take care of that in future posts

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the C-API has changed quite a lot. The [C-Extension chapter](http://python3porting.com/cextensions.html) in Porting to Python 2 provides an introduction. Moving from byte strings to unicode strings is the biggest problem.